# How to access HTML video tag controls in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a video tag in my markup and have included the controls attribute. I was wondering if there was anyway for me to isolate the play button in the DOM to either style it or add a click event to it?

Comment: No way to style built-in controls or add specific event listeners to them. But you can make your custom controls and get full access on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener on the play event, as documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
video.addEventListener('play', playing);

function playing(e) {
   console.log('Playing');
}
```

```css
video {
   width:192px;
   height:108px;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" controls>
```

But there is no way to style the default controls. You'd have to make your own and then use the media events and JavaScript to control the player.